# Can AWS Load Balancer be configured to filter out requests?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django app deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Django is configured to only serve requests that comes for a specific hostname (ALLOWED_HOSTS). If the host information in the request doesn't match, it will raise return 500 response code, that is fine.

But, I have noticed that I get quite many of those, either sending requests vis IP address, or via other domain names. So, I would like to configure the setup so that the load balancer rejects the request if it doesn't have the proper hostname in the header information.

Is this possible to do? I have been trying to go over settings in the AWS Console, but cannot find any information how to do this. I could patch the EC2 instances to reject those request so it doesn't reach Django at all, but I would like to stop it as early as possible.

Flow now:

```
Client -> Load Balancer -> EC2 instance -> Nginx -> Django
                                       <-500 error- Django
```

What I want:

```
Client -> Load Balancer
<-reject- Load Balancer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elastic Load Balancer cannot be configured to filter out requests.

If your allowed connections are based on IP address, then you can use VPC ACLs to allow only connections from certain IP addresses. All others will receive failed connections at the ELB level.

If your allowed connections are not based on IP address you can take a look at CloudFront in combination with Amazon Web Application Firewall (WAF).

WAF can be configured to filter at the web request level by IP address, URL, query string, headers, etc.

Comment: The pattern is to only allow based on hostname. If someone tries to access via IP or other domains, other than the allowed, they should be rejected. WAF looks like the path I would need to go. And small correction, you refer to **Web Application Firewall** when you mention [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/). Thanks!